# Want to select a value from jsf drop down box and after clicking add button need to be displayed in bottom drop down box

Tags: jsf

i am keeping all AppObjects in an array list and able to see them in first drop down box,
after clicking add button what needs to be done at java side and how to display the selected objects in the below drop down box in the form 
Any help is much appreciated and i am new to JSF. Thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="results" ajaxRendered="true">
            <h:panelGrid columns="7">
                <rich:panel header="APP Objects">
                    <rich:select defaultLabel="APP Objects" value="#{searchObjectinDB.chosenAppObject}" listWidth="200">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{searchObjectinDB.AppObjects}" /> 
                        //getting items as list here
                    </rich:select>                                              
                </rich:panel>
                &#160;&#160;&#160;
                <a4j:commandButton id="addAppObject" value="Add" 
                    action="#{searchObjectinDB.getObjectDetails()}" //Upon clicking add button, what needs to be done in this method to show in the below drop down box
                    reRender="selected_objects">
                </a4j:commandButton>
                &#160;&#160;&#160;

                <a4j:outputPanel id="selected_objects">
                    <h:panelGrid columns = "1">
                        <rich:panel header="Selected Objects" style="width: 100%">
                            //need to create another list and display the selected items from first list
                        </rich:panel>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
<h:body>
```

i am keeping all AppObjects in an array list and able to see them in drop down box,
after clicking add button what needs to be done at java side and how to display the selected objects in the below drop down box
Any help is much appreciated and i am new to JSF

Comment: Simply change the order in your arraylist...

Comment: Oh you need a NEW list... Your text was sort of confusing

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple, basically you just need a new collection to keep the selected items. Everytime you call the method getObjectDetails, you add the chosenAppObject variable into your collection of selected items, pretty much like this:

```
public class SearchObjectinDB {

   Object chosenAppObject;
   List<Object> AppObjects;
   List<Object> selectedAppObjects = new ArrayList<>();

   //getters and setters

   public void getObjectDetails() {
      selectedAppObjects.add(chosenAppObject);
   }

}
```

Your XHTML code also needs to create a new list and show the select items:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="results" ajaxRendered="true">
            <h:panelGrid columns="7">
                <rich:panel header="APP Objects">
                    <rich:select defaultLabel="APP Objects" value="#{searchObjectinDB.chosenAppObject}" listWidth="200">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{searchObjectinDB.AppObjects}" /> 
                        //getting items as list here
                    </rich:select>                                              
                </rich:panel>
                &#160;&#160;&#160;
                <a4j:commandButton id="addAppObject" value="Add" 
                    action="#{searchObjectinDB.getObjectDetails()}" //Upon clicking add button, what needs to be done in this method to show in the below drop down box
                    reRender="selected_objects">
                </a4j:commandButton>
                &#160;&#160;&#160;

                <a4j:outputPanel id="selected_objects">
                    <h:panelGrid columns = "1">
                        <rich:panel header="Selected Objects" style="width: 100%">
                            <a4j:repeat value="#{searchObjectinDB.selectedAppObjects}" var="item">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputText value="#{item.toString}" id="item1" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </a4j:repeat>
                        </rich:panel>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
<h:body>
```

Comment: Getting exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: /object-test.xhtml: Property 'chosenAppObject' not found on type java.lang.String root cause: javax.el.ELException: /object-test.xml: Property 'chosenAppObject' not found on type java.lang.String.

Comment: You must have getters (and setters if needed) to expose bean properties to your XHTML file.

Comment: That's because my example didn't show the correct object types. In your case you must not use Object, but else other type. My guess here is String, but even so, the answer is directed to the first problem, you must now debug possible problems to understand what is happening.